# Wordpress Basic looping issue WP_Query

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I am working on developing a wordpress theme and have run into the following issue of the my pages advanced custom fields not being available after getting a custom post type using WP_Query, as shown below:

`index.php` snippet

```
    //passing in the post id of page with advanced custom fields called 'home'
    $indexPosts = new WP_Query("post_type" => "page", $post_id = $post->ID); 

    while($indexPosts->have_posts()){
       $indexPosts->the_post();

       //do stuff with home pages advanced field data, all fields available and working
       get_field('somecustomfield_from_home_page'); //NON empty

       //get custom post
       $customPost = new WP_Query("post_type" => "mycustompost");

       while($customPost->have_posts()){
           $custom_post->the_post();

           //do stuff with custom post data, all is working

       }
       wp_reset_postdata();        

       //trying to do stuff with home pages acf data, all fields empty
        get_field('somecustomfield_from_home_page'); //empty
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
```

Comment: I think its related to you calling `wp_reset_postdata()` and try to access custom fields after resseting them. `wp_reset_postdata()` will reset the global $post, which is used by `get_field()`

Comment: This is not the right answer, but you can use this as a quick fix. Assign the value you are looking for, to a variable at the top of your code above $variable = get_field('somecustomfield_from_home_page'); and call it where ever you need.

Comment: Thanks for the reply guys. @Ajith, as a temporary fix, I believe your suggestion may work, however I am looking for the correct way to implement this / trying to understand if there are any errors in my logic.

Comment: Another question, what is the best way to manage advanced custom fields for the home/index page? What I am currently doing is creating a new page called 'home' w/ the path of `/home` - then running a `WP_Query` on the `index.php` page to retrieve all the custom fields for the `home` page. In the event someone actually navigates to `/home` I will have `htaccess` navigate to `/` (index.php), is this the correct way of implementing this?

Comment: Are you trying to use the custom meta value within your first loop? You're showing it within the `while` statement (where `$post` still references `$indexPosts`). What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: default template for wordpress home page is front-page.php. WP will auto use this template for home page. using ACF values on index.php will raise errors as index.php is used if you have not set relevant template files. Example. if you are accessing post/category archives, but have not set template for that, index.php is the file wp loads there

Comment: @rnevius, I am trying to use custom meta values specific to the homepage, that is represented by the outer while loop above. Within the outer loop, I am trying to use custom meta values for a custom post type. When I am out of the inner loop for the custom post type, I am unable to access custom meta values from the page again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you're using a custom query to output the home page post data. This should be available under the default query. I **highly** recommend using a *front-page.php* page template for your home page (as is [recommended by the docs](https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_a_Static_Front_Page#Custom_Site_Front_Page_Template)). If you do that, you can simplify everything to the following:

```
// Default query / Loop
if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

    // do stuff with advanced field data
    // This will use the $post_id from the default query
    get_field('somecustomfield_from_home_page');

    //get custom post
    $customPost = new WP_Query("post_type" => "mycustompost");

    if ( $customPost->have_posts() ) :
        while ( $customPost->have_posts() ) : $custom_post->the_post();
            //do stuff with custom post data, all is working
        endwhile;
        wp_reset_postdata();        
    endif;

    // do stuff with home pages acf data again
    get_field('somecustomfield_from_home_page');

endwhile; endif;
```

Comment: I do not fully understand how this solves the issue. How will will `front-page.php` know to pull the acf from the `home` page without a `WP_Query`? Assuming I am no longer adding the acf to the `home` page anymore, what post/page am I adding the acf's to, so I can manage it from wp-admin?

Comment: Because the global `$post` object is set by default (and `get_field()` defaults to the current post ID). I recommend reading about [template hierarchy](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/). I'm not sure I understand your second question. You wouldn't change anything about how the fields are currently set up in the admin (assuming the page they're added to is set as the site's [static front page](https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_a_Static_Front_Page)).

Comment: Assuming I get rid of the `home` page and start using `front-page`, `somecustomfield_from_home_page` is no longer linked to the `home` page, right? How would I be able to manage this acf in the wp-admin without a page to link the acf field to?

Comment: I still don't understand...You need to read about how WordPress determines what templates to use. Please read about [static front pages in the Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_a_Static_Front_Page), and give this a shot.

Comment: `somecustomfield_from_home_page` is an advanced custom field. In order for the advanced custom field to be managed from the wp-admin, it needs to be a custom post type or a page of some sort. In my code, the advanced custom fields I am accessing is linked to a published page called 'home'. In your above code, you're suggesting getting rid of `home` page, and using `front-page.php`  instead. How can I manage advanced custom fields on the `font-page` when it is not linked to a custom post or published page / how will `somecustomfield_from_home_page` in your above code be defined?

Comment: No, I'm not suggesting that. Keep the home page in the admin and keep the custom fields set up exactly the same. Add a *front-page.php* template to your theme root. Add the code I wrote above. Set `home` as your "Static Front Page" (see the link I posted in a comment above for how to do this). WordPress will now know to use *front-page.php* to display your "home" page data, because it will set up the global `$post` object to that page automatically. This will also make `$post_id` available to `get_post()`.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying, I think I understand now, let me give this a shot and report back

Comment: It worked as explained, its actually a lot more straightforward than what I thought, I appreciate the help :)